# Creating lists while code is running and adding them to an List Parent

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I am trying to create lists based on a value given by the user input and then I would like to add those lists created to a Parent list where they all can be accessed and used.

For example, I want the for loop to grab the number entered by the user, and based on that number it needs to create lists numbered from 1 to whatever they chose. At the end of each repetition I would like to add the created list to a parent list.

Here is what I have so far, I am struggling in adding them to the parent list I guess.

```
lists = int(input("How many lists do you want? "))
varname = 'iteration_number_'
parent_list = []

for i in range(lists):
    iteration_number = i+1 #So it does not start from 0
    iteration_names = varname + str(iteration_number) #merging the name and the number

    x = parent_list.append(exec(f"{iteration_names} = []")) #creating lists with that name

try:
    iteration_number_1.append("Cow") # appends Cow to the first list if existing
    iteration_number_2.append("Moo") # appends Moo to the first list if existing

    print(iteration_number_1)
    print(iteration_number_2)

except NameError:
    pass

print(parent_list)
parent_list[0].append("This is list iteration_number_1 but I'm not working")
```

The last part of the code doesn't work as planned. In my head when I print parent_list I should get [[iteration_number_1], [iteration_number_2]] and they can be accessed like this

```
parent_list[0].append("Hello") #appending to the iteration_number_1 list
```

Does anyone know a better idea? or how to make this idea work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmers call them `nested lists`:

```
myNestedList = [
    [1, 2, 3], 
    [4, 5, 6], 
    [7, 8, 9]
]
```

You can access the inner `list`s this way:

```
>>> myNestedList[0] # Get the first row
[1, 2, 3]
>>> myNestedList[0][2]
3
```

You can append elements to the inner lists this way:

```
>>> myNestedList[0].append(10)
>>> myNestedList
[[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

---

I saw you are using `str`ings as keys instead of `int`egers, this way:

```
iteration_names = varname + str(iteration_number) #merging the name and the number
x = parent_list.append(exec(f"{iteration_names} = []")) #creating lists with that name
```

In your case it's a bad idea, but you could use `dict`ionaries, this way:

```
myDict: dict = {
    "iteration_name_1": <first-element-of-the-list>,
    "iteration_name_2": <second-el...>
}
```

You can access the dictionary this way:

```
>>> myDict['iteration_name_1']
<first-element...>
```

---

If you tried this at the end of the program:

```
parent_list[0].append(iteration_name_1)
```

and it didn't work, I would suggest to create the lists by name this way (if you really need to call them with names like 'name_x'):

```
>>> locals()['iteration_name_1'] = []
>>> iteration_name_1
[]
```

---

It has nothing to do with the question, but...

```
for i in range(lists):
iteration_number = i+1 #So it does not start from 0
```

...you should know that a better practice is to do this:

```
for i in range(1, lists):
    # i starts from 1
```

## All and all...

---

The best practice would be doing this way:

```
for i in range(lists):
    parent_list.append([])
try:
    parent_list[0].append('Cow')
    parent_list[1].append('Moo')
except IndexError: # There is a different exception for an element not found in parent_list
    pass
```

[image: It worked for me]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my main code, yes I have nested lists. The problem is creating those nested lists from lists that are being created inside the for-loop while the code is running.

Comment: It's a really bad practice to create lists with exec... I'm going to make an attempt to answer you, but you really shouldn't do it this way...

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer.
I didn't quite understand your reasoning why my solution didn't work. I know I am changing it in both the parent and child, since they are connected. Also I tried this part: 

for i in range(lists):
    parent_list[ i ] = [ ]

but it didn't work, I don't see how this is creating multiples of lists.
I do like the dictionary idea, filling it with lists, and accessing them. I'm looking into some documentation about that atm.

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should work. If you need more help contact me on Discord at FLAK_FLAK#3241

Comment: Thank you very much, It's insane how this line solves everything:
 parent_list.append([ ])


Thank you again for the help! Also the dic method worked too, but this one is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to a dictionary with the key as a string to the iteration number and the value as a list:

```
d = {}
d["iteration_number_1"] = []
...

d["iteration_number_1"].append("hello")
```